# "symmetry" in the sense of Abel-Jacobi map of hyperelliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I met such a very interesting problem in algebraic curves (from Griffiths' Introduction to algebraic curves):

Denote by $u: Div(C)\rightarrow Jac(C)$ the Abel-Jacobi map of the compact Riemann surface $C$. Identify $C$ with the subset $\{1\cdot p ~|~p\in C\}$ of $Div(C)$. Then $u(C)=-u(C)$ iff $C$ is hyperelliptic.

I'm a beginner and I only know the basic definition of a hyperelliptic surface, namely admitting a 2-fold holomorphic mapping onto $\mathbb{P}^1$. Is there any further properties of hyperelliptic surfaces that I can use to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you can take base point $p_0$ to be fixed by hyperelliptic involution $\tau$, then show that $\int_{p_0}^p=-\int_{p_0}^{\tau(p)}$.

Comment: @AGlearner thanks! but I have a further question: does the result $u(C)=-u(C)$ depend on the choice of the base point $p_0$?

Comment: @AGlearner I am a little puzzled. I think the geometric interpretation would tell me $\int _{p_{0}} ^p=\int _{p_{0}} ^{\tau(p)}$, without the sign; because locally that isn't a ramification point. (This is also the reason why I can't complete the proof at beginning. )  Could you please explain the geometric intuition of the sign? thanks!

Comment: Here is my intuition: The derivative of Abel-Jacobi map is the canonical map, but the canonical map is 2:1 so I regard it as an even function, say $x\mapsto x^2$ on $\mathbb R$. Now its antiderivative $x\mapsto \int_0^x(x^2)=\frac13x^3$ is an odd function, so that's why $u(C)$ is symmetric. Note that I choose base point to be ramification point, and shifting graph of an odd function will not be odd, so the base point really matters.

Comment: @AGlearner  Thank you. So to be precise, the argument should be modified as "there exists a base point of $C$ s.t. the Abel-Jacobi map has the property $u(C)=-u(C)$". But I still don't know how to write the proof in a rigorous way...and how about the necessity?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the statement is based on some elementary observations in Calculus:
$$\textit{The antiderivative of an even function is an odd function},$$

when picking the critical point as the base point, and the other direction is more or less:

$$\textit{If an antiderivative of a function}~f~\textit{is odd, then}~f~ \textit{is even}.$$

We should apply the "odd function" to the Abel-Jacobi map $u:X\to JX$, and the "even function" to the canonical mapping $u:X\to \mathbb P^{g-1}$ (or maybe its dual space) by noting that the canonical mapping derived from the derivative of the Abel-Jacobi map $$du:TX\to \mathbb PT(JX)\cong JX\times \mathbb P^{g-1}\to \mathbb P^{g-1},$$
by sending $x$ to $[\omega_1(x):\omega_2(x):\cdots:\omega_g(x)]$ which vanish at the tangent line at $x$.

Here is the proof. For sufficiency: Suppose $X$ is a hyperelliptic curve, then it is a two-sheeted cover of $\mathbb P^1$ along $2g+2$ points $p_1,...p_{2g+2}$. We draw slits between $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$ for $i$ odd, then $X$ can be thought as two copy of $\mathbb C$ glued along the $g+1$ segments (and with an $\infty$ point added). Let's say $p_1=0$ and $p_2=1$. We choose $0$ to be our base point.

Then a point on the "lower sheet" can be joined to $0$ by a path $l$ which does not cross any of the slit, while a point on the "upper sheet" can be joined to $0$ by a path $l'$ which cross the slit $[0,1]$.

In particular, if the point on the lower sheet $x$ and the point on upper sheet $x'$ have the same "shadow" (same image under the canonical map), $$l+l'+\gamma=0,$$ where $\gamma$ is a loop homologous to a small circle encompassing $[0,1]$ and represents a nonzero homology class in $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)$. In other words, the Abel-Jacobi image of $x$ and $x'$ differ by a sign:

$$u(x)=-u(x').$$

For necessity, since $u(X)=-u(X)$, for any $x\in X$, the inverse map on the ambient torus defines a holomorphic map $\tau:X\to X$. Since it is an involution,

$$x+\tau(x)=0,$$

and the equation is complex differentiable with respect to the parameter $x$. Taking the differential gives

$$dx+d\tau(x)=0.$$

This says that as the holomorphic differential, $dx=-d\tau(x)$, so in the projective space $(\mathbb P^{g-1})^*$, $[dx]=[d\tau(x)]$. Therefore, the canonical mapping of $X$ is not injective, thus $X$ has to be Hyperelliptic.

Comment: Oh, I understand! Thank you very much for the precise proof!